# Unsuccessful loop exit

Tags: excel, vba

Why does the loop not end ?   (if msgbox is active, it shows value "B")

```
Sub sssssssscrscr()
    x = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXZWY"
    For i = 1 To Len(x)
        For j = 1 To Len(x)
            ActiveCell.Value = Mid(x, i, j)
            'MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
            If ActiveCell.Value = "B" Then Exit For
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You have two `For` loops and are only exiting the first one.

Comment: The loop *does* end. Not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand what your required output is.  The loops end with activecell = "Y"  If you want it to stop at B, why not use Exit sub instead of exit for?  Is it that x is only an example of the real data you're processing?

Comment: after "B" is found, I need macro to continue

Comment: The location of `ActiveCell` is never changed in the code above.  If you *are* using `Offset` or `Find`, or something else, edit the code to include it. See [MCVE].

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `Exit For` you could put in `Exit Sub` to get out of the macro entirely

Answer (score 1):

as Doug Glancy says, one more exit needed :)

```
Sub sssssssscrscr()
x = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXZWY"
For i = 1 To Len(x)
For j = 1 To Len(x)
ActiveCell.Value = Mid(x, i, j)
'MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
If ActiveCell.Value = "B" Then Exit For
Next
If ActiveCell.Value = "B" Then Exit For
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need **any** loops.

Since you are changing `ActiveCell's` location within the loop(s), all you need is:

```
ActiveCell.Value = "B"
```

Comment: He isn't changing the location of the `ActiveCell` he's only updating the value in it.

Answer (score 0):

This will change the value of the same cell multiple times without changing what cell is being updated.

If you want to leave the loops then you will need to exit both of them. You can use a `GoTo` to accomplish this like this:

```
Sub sssssssscrscr()
    x = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXZWY"
    For i = 1 To Len(x)
        For j = 1 To Len(x)
            ActiveCell.Value = Mid(x, i, j)
            'MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
            If ActiveCell.Value = "B" Then goto EndLoop
        Next
    Next
    EndLoop:
    'more code goes here
End Sub
```

After the `EndLoop:` you can then also add anything else that you want to be done before the macro ends.

If you let us know what this is supposed to be doing we could help more. With the limited info that you've provided this is probably all we can really do.